# Ruby: How to calculate a path relative to another one?

Tags: ruby, relative-path

Let's say I know the absolute path that I am starting from and the absolute path that I am trying to get to:

```
first = '/first/path'
second = '/second/path'
```

Now I want to figure out how to construct a path that is relative to the first. For example:

```
# answer should be /first/path/../../second/path
path = second.get_path_relative_to(first)
```

How can I do this sort of thing in Ruby?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use [`Pathname#relative_path_from`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-relative_path_from):

```
require 'pathname'

first = Pathname.new '/first/path'
second = Pathname.new '/second/path'

relative = second.relative_path_from first
# ../../second/path

first + relative
# /second/path
```