# Converting an absolute path to a relative one

Tags: ruby, file, path, relative-path, absolute-path

Converting a relative path `foo` with respect to reference point `bar` into an absolute path `baz` can be done by:

```
baz = File.expand_path(foo, bar)
```

How can the opposite of this be done? In other words, given an absolute path `baz` and reference point `bar` (given as absolute path), how can it be converted into a relative path `foo` as below?

```
foo = File.relative_path(baz, bar)
```

Please assume that all given paths are normalized in the sense that they do not end with `/` in case they are directories:

```
"/foo/bar"
"/foo/bar/" # No need to consider
```

and the same applies to all returned paths.

Note that this is not as trivial as stripping away `bar` from the initial part of `baz` and replacing it with `./` because `baz` is not necessarily a descendant of `bar`. In general, a number of `../` have to be stacked to reach the common ancestor.

Examples include, but are not limited to:

```
File.relative_path("/foo/bar/quex", "/foo") # => "bar/quex" (preferred) or
                                            #    "./bar/quex"
File.relative_path("/foo", "/foo/bar") # => "../"
File.relative_path("/foo/bar", "/baz/quex") # => "../../foo/bar"
```

Comment: Woww.. What a thought it is.. +1

Comment: It came out of necessity, it is not only for curiosity. :)

Comment: hehe... Still.. *Wooww* .. you deserve it. It would be good I think, to think for me, If you really give some real path as an example. So that I/we can visualize your need.

Comment: Why *close-vote* to this post ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe [`Pathname#relative_path_from`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-relative_path_from) is what you're looking for. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11471495/512904) I gave to another question.

```
require 'pathname'

first = Pathname.new '/first/path'
second = Pathname.new '/second/path'

relative = second.relative_path_from first
# ../../second/path

first + relative
# /second/path
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped. Just for future reference to others: `to_s` should be applied to the result.